# split the code into header file and main code

Tags: c++, binary-operators

I try to split the code to header file and main code, but I'm not sure how to do it.
specifically, I have problem when I write the operator in the header file. I always get " overloaded operator must be a binary operator". I tried to use friend function for the overloading operator, but it doesn't work( I got same error above)
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
class Cash{
        private:
                int dollars;  //private members of the class
                int cents;
                double cash;
                string amt="$";
        public: 
        Cash(int dollars, int cents )  // parameterised constructor accepting two int inputs
        {
                this->dollars=dollars;
                this->cents=cents;
                setcash();         //Calling setcash method to set the cash value
        }
        Cash(int dollars)  //parameterised constructor accepting one int input
        {
                this->dollars=dollars;
                cents=0;
                setcash();  //Calling setcash method to set the cash value
        }
        Cash()  //default constructor
        {
                dollars=0;
                cents=0;
                setcash();  //Calling setcash method to set the cash value
        }
        int getdollar()  //method to return dollar value
        {
                return dollars;
        }
        int getcents() //method to return cents value
        {
                return cents;
        }
        void setcash()  //setcash method definition
        {   if (cents==0)
            {
                cash=(double)dollars;
                return;}
                /* converting cent value into dollar to get total cash amount */
                double centindouble=(double)cents;
                double centsindollar=centindouble/pow(10,floor(log10(abs(cents)) + 1)); 
                cash=(double)dollars + centsindollar;
            
        }
        double getcash()  //method to return net cash
        {   
                return cash;
        }
        string toString() //converting cash into string as per question
        {
                
            amt=amt+to_string(cash);
            return amt;
        }
        bool operator ==(Cash &c) //overloading == operator to compare two cash obj
        {
                if(getcash()==c.getcash())
                return true;
                else
                return false;
        }
        bool operator >(Cash &c)//overloading > operator to compare two cash obj
        {
                if(getcash()>c.getcash())
                return true;
                else 
                return false;
        }
        bool operator <(Cash &c)//overloading < operator to compare two cash obj
        {
                if(getcash()<c.getcash())
                return true;
                else 
                return false;
        }
        Cash operator+(Cash c) //overloading + operator to add values of two cash obj
        {
                int dlr=dollars+c.getdollar();
                int cts=cents+c.getcents();
                Cash c1(dlr,cts);
                return c1;
        }

        Cash operator-(Cash &c) //overloading - operator to subtract values of two cash obj
        {  int dlr=dollars-c.getdollar();
                int cts=cents-c.getcents();
                Cash c1(dlr,cts);
                return c1;
        }
        void operator *(int n)//overloading * operator to multiply values of cash obj
        {
          dollars=dollars*n;
          cents=cents*n;
          setcash();    
        }
};

/* Driver Method to Test our Program */
int main()
{
    Cash c(100,5);
    Cash a(100,5);
    if(c==a)
    cout<<"Equal "<<endl;
    Cash d=c+a;
    Cash f=c-a;
    cout<<c.getcash()<<endl;
    cout<<d.getcash()<<endl;
    cout<<f.getcash()<<endl;
    cout<<d.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to just what you need to reproduce the error. Focus on the overloaded operator, and get rid of what is extraneous to that operator (c.f. [mre]). Also, it would be helpful to point out where in the program the error is triggered.

Comment: Don't you need to return something from the main function as well, like return 0?

Comment: @The_Redhawk The [main function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function#Explanation) is special in that it does not need an explicit `return` statement (point 4 in the linked page).

Comment: I never knew that. Thank you for the link. Learn something every day.

Answer (score -1):

In the code you provide, all your methods are both declared and defined.

To split in .h/.cpp  you need the declaration in the .h and the definition in the .cpp

.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
class Cash{
        private:
          int dollars;  //private members of the class
          int cents;
          double cash;
          string amt="$";
        public: 
          Cash(int dollars, int cents );
          Cash(int dollars);
          Cash();
          int getdollar();
          int getcents();
          void setcash();
          double getcash();
          string toString();
          bool operator ==(Cash &c);
          bool operator >(Cash &c);
          bool operator <(Cash &c);
          Cash operator+(Cash c);
          Cash operator-(Cash &c);
          void operator *(int n);   
};
```

.cpp (only one method given in example)

```
#include "whateveryourname.h"

    Cash::Cash()  //default constructor
    {
            dollars=0;
            cents=0;
            setcash();  //Calling setcash method to set the cash value
    }
```

also, i would initialise the string `amt` in the constructor.

Comment: It is legal, and sometimes desirable, to both declare and define `inline` functions in a header file. A default constructor that zeros out values is a prime candidate for this.

Comment: @JaMiT, My understanding is that is exactly the question "how to split in .h and .cpp".

Comment: I wrote as you told me, but I still get error```bool operator Cash::==(Cash &c) //overloading == operator to compare two cash obj
{
 if (getCash() == c.getCash())
  return true;
 else
  return false;
}```there is a error on the "Cash:: and getCash(). I think I put the Cash:: in the wrong place.

Comment: if you put the definition in the cpp file as i suggested: bool Cash::operator==(Cash &c){code in here}